# ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8')

Tags: php, utf-8, mbstring, ini-set

```
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8')
```

what does this signify at the beginning of a php file and what is it used for ?

I know that a php manual exists but it does not explain it in plain common man's language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines the default internal character encoding to UTF-8 character set type.

This is used to make a site multilingual by changing the `mbstring.internal_encoding` value.

> encoding is the character encoding name used for the HTTP input
>   character encoding conversion, HTTP output character encoding
>   conversion, and the default character encoding for string functions
>   defined by the mbstring module. You should notice that the internal
>   encoding is totally different from the one for multibyte regex.

And UTF-8 (8-bit Unicode Transformation Format) is a variable-length character encoding for Unicode.

You can change it using the `iso-8859-1`, `UTF-8`, etc.

Here is the list of [Unicode character list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).